# run progress bar with time interval changing at every loop

Tags: javascript

I have made a progress bar with decrease from `width` 100 to 0 using `setInterval` function. So basically every 20ms my width decrease from 1. Then when the `width` arrives at 0, I set the `width` to 100 to run the progress bar again. At every loop, I change the text inside my progress bar. What I'd like to do now is change the time interval (the 20ms) at every loop.

Si in my code, when I increase from one, my 20 is replaced by `interval[i]`... but I am stack to put setInterval inside a loop...

The code below works to change the text at every loop, but don't know how to improve it to change the time interval at every iteration of i...

```js
function move() {
  var message = ['test', 'test2', 'test3'];
  var interval = [10, 20, 30]
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

  var width = 100;
  var i = 0;

  var id = setInterval(frame, 20);

  function frame() {

    width = width - 1;
    elem.style.width = width + "%";
    elem.textContent = message[i];
    if (width == 0 && i < 3) {
      width = 100;
      i++;
    }
    if (i == 3) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"> </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that it would be more appropriate to use `setTimeout(..)` 
instead of `setInterval(..)` if you should change the interval at the iterations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout `setTimeout(...)` runs once `setTimeout(...)` runs until you stop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"> </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

<script>

function move() {
        var message = ['test','test2','test3'];
        var interval = [10,20,30]
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

        var width = 100;
        var i = 0;


        var id = setInterval(frame, interval[i]);

      function frame() {

          width = width - 1;
          elem.style.width = width + "%";
          elem.textContent = message[i];
          if (width == 0 && i < 3) {
            width = 100;
            i++;
            clearInterval(id);
            id = setInterval(frame, interval[i]);
          }

          if (i == 3) {
            clearInterval(id);
          }
        }

      }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable outside function `move` that holds the iteration time step, like:

```
let iterationStep = 0;
```

Then inside

```
let iterationStep = 0;

function move() {

    //...blabla

    var id = setInterval(frame, interval[iterationStep]);

  function frame() {

      // blablabla

      if (width == 0 && i < 3) {
        width = 100;
        i++;
      // HERE
        iterationStep = i;
      } 

       //blablabla
    }

  }
```

So each time you are increasing i you are also increasing the value of iterationStep by i value. And it is the value that will be used to access the postition inside the array of intervals of the iteration once you click in `move()`.

Comment: this is not working. I have tried it, but the iterationStep is never send to the move function to uptade the setInterval...

Comment: How it is not send? It is inside the SCOPE of the variable, so it must have acces to it. If you use console.log(iterationStep) inside move, and inside frame you will see the value of iterationStep.

Comment: yes agree, but the setInterval function is not updated with my array interval...